# WebApplication.Models.Category instead of value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to add a `DropDownList` in my `Insert` View.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(Category.GetCategories());
    return View("Insert", new Category()); 
}
```

View:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) 
   (ViewBag.CategoryList), "Select Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The `Category` class has only one `string` field named `Title`. Instead of getting the value of `Title` I'm getting `WebApplication.Models.Category`.

Comment: At the statement `return View("Insert", new Category())` you bind new instance of the `Category` class to the `model` property of your razor page. It means the type of the `model` property is `Category` itself. So it looks a bit strange statement like `model.Category` because the model shouldn't have this property but should have `model.Title`. Couldn't you please clarify how you declare @model on the page.

Comment: @Kitta I have a `Product` model which has a `Category` property. `@model` on the page is `@model WebApplication1.Models.Product`

Comment: That means that you have discrepancy between instance that you passed to the page and your model declaration. I guess, first of all you need something like `return View("Insert", new Product())` in the controller method. After that you be able to address to the Title property via `model.Category.Title` statement or bind your dropdownbox to the Category property using `m => m.Category`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the `Title` is defined as property and not a field to be data binding work properly.

Then try the following:

```cs
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CategoryList = Category.GetCategories();
    return View("Insert", new Product()); 
}
```

And in the `Insert` view:

```
@using WebApplication1.Models @* Category namespace *@
@model WebApplication1.Models.Product

@{   
    IEnumerable<Category> categories = (IEnumerable<Category>)ViewBag.CategoryList;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => categories.GetEnumerator().Current,
          categories.Select(d =>
          {
              return new SelectListItem() { Text = d.Title, Value = d.Title };
          }),
          "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: @EL02: Can you explain why you pass one instance of the `Category` to the `Insert` view as the view model? It looks strange. It would be more logical to pass list of the all categories, instead of using the `ViewBag`.

Comment: I too am kinda lost here. First time dealing with dropdownlists.  I have a `Product` model which has a string `Category` property. `@model` on the page is `@model WebApplication1.Models.Product`. I want to pass the value of the selected option to `model.Category`

Comment: @EL02: Ok. Then in the `Create` method just replace `Category.GetCategories();` with code that populate the  ViewBag.CategoryList collection. It should be of type `List<Category>`.

Comment: I get this error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[WebApplication1.Models.Category]'.`

And yes i did also change the controller

Comment: @EL02: It's because you have `ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(Category.GetCategories());` line in the `Create` method. I suggest replace this line by `ViewBag.CategoryList = Category.GetCategories();` one. I suppose the `Category.GetCategories()` creating an List<Category>.

Comment: I have already done that. After cleaning and rebuilding the solution it works!!! Thanks a lot. Now i gotta figure out why it works. Again Thanks a lot!